# Reuse queryset in multiple views

Tags: django, view, django-queryset, reusability

I am building a application which has several views - HomePageView, SearchPageView and DetailPageView. The aforementioned views return the same queryset. My question is, what is the proper way to define let's say a "global" queryset which would be then used in multiple Views.

To illustrate my point here is an example of what I have:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
   def get_queryset():
      return Systemevents.objects.filter(**filter)

class SearchPageView(ListView):
   def get_queryset():
      return Systemevents.objects.filter(**filter)

class LogDetailView(DetailView):
   def get_queryset():
      return Systemevents.objects.filter(**filter)
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
global queryset = Systemevents.objects.filter(**filter)

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
   def get_queryset():
      return queryset

class SearchPageView(ListView):
   def get_queryset():
      return queryset

class LogDetailView(DetailView):
   def get_queryset():
      return queryset
```

Thanks in advance,
Jordan

Answer (score 1):

you can use something called manager for that for reusing that query set you have to specify all your logic inside the django manager so you don't have to go for a long query set just small readable query set checkout more about in the django documentation

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/